# Don't raise window on click (while hold)

Tags: compiz, window-manager

It seems that Compiz support forum is used for spam, and as I noticed similar questions answered here, I thought it'd be best for me to ask here

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and window manager uses Compiz

While on Windows I got used to this feature which I'll try to explain:

Imagine simple drag&drop operation - I have *Explorer* maximized and I open *Notepad* on top of it. Now, if I click and hold mouse button on a file in *Explorer*, *Notepad* loses focus but it's still visible - *Explorer* window isn't raised over it, so I can finish my drag&drop operation. That's not happening on Linux, and I want to make it somehow.

In Compiz 'General options' there are similar settings, but nothing can bring me this feature back it seems. Sourced from Internet it seems also that Openbox window manager allows this feature while pressing *Super/Win* keyboard button.

So I want to know if this is somehow possible with Compiz or alternatively Metacity

(I know that I can hover on *Launcher*, then raise application and drop, but for some reason it's not reliable always[1], and I find above feature more easier)

[1] *Launcher shades, then hovered application raises but it does not accept dropped source*

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer this question myself, in case someone else looks for this feature. As said, I was unable to make it work with Compiz, then for some other reasons I decided to remove Compiz and install Unity 2D with Metacity. Good move for me, as now I found that while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> key, application used as drag & drop source isn't raised :)

Let me explain once more using Linux naming:

Maximize Nautilus (it doesn't have to be miximized of course, but it's easier to explain this way). Launch Gedit. While GEdit is on top, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>, then drag some text file from Nautilus and drop it on Gedit window, which is still on top and even did not lose focus.