# Raise window on mouse up event instead of click event in ubuntu

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager

Main problem is drag and drop from a maximize windows to another window(not maximized). I have a maximized nautilus window and i want to drag and drop a file into skype window. But as soon as i click on file, skype will hide under nautilus window. Also drag file on unity launcher does't work in ubuntu 14.04, specially when there are multiple window (for one launcher icon).

We can simulate this by disable the option "Raise on click" in compiz settings. But this option also create problem to raise the window. I think if we can configure that "Raise window on mouse up(left button) event" then drag and drop problem can be solve. I googled for a long time but no luck. I am almost sure, there is no option to do this.

I also didn't find any hints to do this. I am a developer, i can code. I need to know the point where to start. Can someone help me to find the way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Three years](http://superuser.com/questions/305202/raise-windows-after-release-mouse-button) and still no luck, eh? :( This is something I'd like to have too. There's [a workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/995039/comments/5) linked in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/191371/158442).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I was used this workaround a long time ago. Now i want fix it(real way) and need some coding help(pointing out the packages, other information).

Comment: @muru I think it also can't possible now, "Drag an item on a launcher and only the window related to that launcher will be shown in spread mode". Assume i have 2 skype window, and when i drag a file on skype launcher, 2 skype window will be shown in spread mode.

Comment: I think the first component to look at is the window manager (`compiz` in this case, but it also affects `mutter` and derivatives). It seems `metacity` is able to do [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57752/dont-raise-window-on-click-while-hold?rq=1), so you could look at how the WMs handle these events.

Answer (score 0):

looks like [unity drag & drop files to another window](https://askubuntu.com/q/123948/163693)

In resumen

1. Start dragging the file
2. Press and hold Super (windows key) + Tab (do not release the mouse button)
3. Hold Super and press Tab as many time you need to choose your file window destination
4. Release Super when you have selected the correct window
5. Release mouse button to drop the file

Comment: There are workaround (easy or difficult), but i am looking for solution and coding help. I have better solution, use scale plugin(ccsm) and set a corner to initiate scale view. Drag the file to specific corner, when scale view active then move the cursor on desire window and wait to exit from scale mode